# Movie where people try to kill a possessed woman with morphine

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, ghost, demons

I watched a movie where some woman was being haunted by a demon. I think it appeared as a human man with a painted face.

During a writing exercise of some kind, a teacher or professor tells the people present to write a letter to someone that has been troubling them and to do something with the letter. I think it was to burn it or destroy it in another way, though I'm not sure. The woman writes her letter to the demon, saying that she has convinced herself that it doesn't exist. I think the writing was in English, so this was either a British or American movie, most likely.

I don't remember the rest of the movie except for the ending. In the end, the woman is in a house along with a couple other people. They strap her down to a hospital bed, draw a circle of salt around it, and put her on an IV drip. The demon appears and tells the woman to take his hand and give control over her body to him, then tells her that the other characters have given her a lethal dose of morphine. To the other characters, the woman remarks that her hand is going numb, at which point one of the other characters starts crying and asks her for forgiveness for what they have done. As the woman is about to go unconscious from the morphine, she takes the demon's hand and he possesses her.

The movie ends with the possessed woman going around killing the characters (Although, IIRC, the last shot is just that of a house, and we hear screams and the sound of bones breaking).

Comment: No, this is definitely not Queen of Spades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The Last Exorcism Part II* (2013).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Exorcism_Part_II):

> Nell witnesses many strange happenings there, **including masked men watching her.** Her personality changes as things get darker. She begins to get hints that the demon Abalam is back.
>
> When Stephanie, one of the girls at the house, dies of an unnatural seizure, Cecile, Nell's former nurse, informs her of the Order of the Right Hand, a secret society which has been monitoring Nell. [...] They attempt to rid the demon which is "in love" with Nell by transferring it into the body of a sacrificed chicken. **The supernatural force in Nell proves to be too powerful, and Calder is forced to kill her by injecting her with a lethal dose of morphine.**
>
> The demon appears in front of Nell, taking her appearance as a doppelganger, her father, and Chris, and begs her to accept its hand. Nell's pulse stops temporarily and leads Calder, Jeffrey, and Cecile, to believe that she has died. **She finally gives in and grabs the demon's hand; the house is left to burn with the three secret society members being killed. Nell murders Frank and burns the home for girls, leaving her friends to die.** Nell gets inside a car and the prophecy of the end of times is proven to be correct as she sets multiple buildings and vehicles aflame while driving past them.

[This review](https://certifiedforgotten.com/the-last-exorcism-part-2/) has the bit about the letter:

> “I’ve decided you’re not real,” she writes in a letter to the demon Abalam, part of an exercise assigned at her new group home. Nell’s face relaxes, and for the first time, she smiles.

---

Found with the Google query `horror movie demon possess lethal morphine site:en.wikipedia.org`.